# Azure Media Analytics vs Cognitive Services Video API

Tags: azure, video, analytics, azure-cognitive-services, azure-media-services

Azure is coming is with new Video Analytics API under the Azure Media Analytics(AMA) bracket, and looks promising. In the meantime, Azure Cognitive Services has also come up with Video API which can do some of the analytics jobs which already exist in AMA. 
                                                      Why is Microsoft following these two different tracks to come up with analytics solution, rather than having one team look at it completely ?

Answer (score 0):

Cognitive Services was designed to be a lightweight series of API's enabling cognitive capabilities for application developers.  This suite comprised different forms of AI such as speech and image analysis, in addition to Video.

In the case of the Video APIs, these are actually hosted as Media Processors on the Azure Media Services (AMS) platform at the core.

Comment: Thanks @asolanki for the answer. Surely clears my concepts 

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Adarsh has stated above, the other area to watch out for is compliance requirements.  There are different terms of use for Cognitive Services like Video Indexer vs. Azure Media Services.  At this time, if you need a fully compliant service with the Azure Terms of services, then you should look at Azure Media Services/Analytics.  If you are ok with the Cognitive Services terms of service and lack of full compliance that Azure has, then you can look at videoindexer.ai.

Over time, we will be bringing more compliance to the Video Indexer platform as well, but since that is a newer set of features it will take some time.

Comment: Thanks @johndeu for the answer. Surely clears my concepts 

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer for almost the same question but in relation to audio transcription only. Found [that](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-azure-media-services):

> Microsoft has been developing a set of services for speech, face and
>   emotion recognition for quite some time, previously known as “Project
>   Oxford”. These services have now been bundled together in a single
>   pack called as Microsoft Cognitive Services. All of its components are
>   now made available to Azure Media Services and branded as “Azure Media
>   Analytics”. It makes video searchable and more accessible to users by
>   indexing its content.

As I understand Azure Media Services use "Cognitive Services" for analytics.

Update: Apparently, [they don't know yet either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822466/difference-among-microsoft-speech-products-platforms).